# date object not updating when calling the setInterval method in React stateful component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, setinterval, stateful

I'm new to react and I'm trying to practice stateful components.  My goal is to have hour, minute, and seconds be updated using setInterval method.  I first tried using 
`this.setState({ 
     seconds: date.getSeconds()
})`
But to no avail.  I then tried using the prevState approach.  Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Here's my full code:

````
import InputDisplay from './components/InputDisplay';

class Stateful extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            inputName: "",
            inputValue: "Juice",
            hour: 0,
            minute: 0,
            seconds: 0
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.startClock();
    }

    handleOnChangeInput = (e) => {
        let {name, value} = e.target

        this.setState({
            [name]: name,
            inputValue: value
        })
    }

    startClock = () =>{
        const date = new Date();

        setInterval(() =>{
            console.log(this.state.seconds);
            let seconds = date.getSeconds()
            console.log(seconds);
            this.setState(prevState => {
                return {
                    hour: prevState.hour = date.getHours(),
                    minute: prevState.minute = date.getMinutes(),
                    seconds: prevState.seconds = date.getSeconds()
                }
            })
        }, 1000
        )
    }


    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Hello this is Stateful Input: {this.state.inputValue} </h1>
                <InputDisplay 
                    name={this.state.inputName}
                    value= {this.state.inputValue}
                    onChange= {this.handleOnChangeInput}
                />

                <h3>H:{this.state.hour} M:{this.state.minute} S:{this.state.seconds}</h3>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Stateful;```
````

Comment: Can you share the error you get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few issues with your code.

1) setting state is not correct

2) you need to store intervalId in state and clear the interval on component unmount

Try it like this:

```
import InputDisplay from './components/InputDisplay';

class Stateful extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        inputName: "",
        inputValue: "Juice",
        hour: 0,
        minute: 0,
        seconds: 0,
        intervalId: null,
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      const intervalId = setInterval(this.startClock, 1000);
      // store intervalId in the state so it can be accessed later:
      this.setState({intervalId: intervalId});
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      // use intervalId from the state to clear the interval
      clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
    }

    startClock = () => {
      const date = new Date();
      const hour = date.getHours()
      const minute = date.getMinutes()
      const seconds = date.getSeconds()

      this.setState({
        hour,
        minute,
        seconds
      })
    }

    handleOnChangeInput = (e) => {
      let {name, value} = e.target

      this.setState({
        [name]: name,
        inputValue: value
      })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Hello this is Stateful Input: {this.state.inputValue} </h1>
                <InputDisplay 
                    name={this.state.inputName}
                    value= {this.state.inputValue}
                    onChange= {this.handleOnChangeInput}
                />

                <h3>H:{this.state.hour} M:{this.state.minute} S:{this.state.seconds}</h3>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Stateful;
```

Comment: Thank you for responding!  Is it because I did not declare and assign the setInterval into a variable that React did not like?